# Why is the drawing color not updating in JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, colors, jframe, awt

So I was writing a program for my java class and just for fun. It draws fractals, its pretty simple in what it does. I got every component of it working except color changing the points I'm drawing. I think I'm doing it right, but I'm clearly not and since this is my first project with JFrame I'm totally stuck. Here's my paint function. (I know its kind of inefficient pulling values from global arrays but I'm drawing dots here so the optimization isn't that important)

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {

    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

        g.setColor(new Color((int)Math.random()*256, (int)Math.random()*256, (int)Math.random()*256));
        g.drawRect(toX(arr[i], (float)(arr[i])), toY(arr[i], (float)(arr[i])), 1, 1);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(int)Math.random()*256`

Casts have very high priority. Casting the result of `random()` will round it down to `0`. Multiplying that by 256 is still zero. This will always be `Color(0, 0, 0)` - black. Adding extra parentheses should fix it. Or use the `float`s constructor without the multiply.

**Side notes**

You should `@Override` `paintComponent` in Swing, but not in `JFrame`. Extend `JComponent` and add that to the frame.

Global array shouldn't be inefficient, but any global mutables are a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

As a side note (I usually extend `JPanel` but `JComponent` will work as well) you need to ensure you do the following:

```java
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g); //<-------Do this.
    // rest of your code
    // here
}
```

Otherwise the window will not be updated correctly. Specifically.

1. `setColor` in your subclass will not work properly.
2. The subclass's window not be properly redrawn each time `repaint()` is called.

Other problems may also occur.